# How to add appendix in thesis using LyX

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, appendices, thesis

I want to add an appendix (questionnaire etc.) at the end of my thesis after the references. I use the `article` class and work with LyX: `Document -> Start appendix here`. But I am not getting it in the TOC.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{document_fontcolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\color{document_fontcolor}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\PassOptionsToPackage{normalem}{ulem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
%% A simple dot to overcome graphicx limitations
\newcommand{\lyxdot}{.}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\appendix
\noindent \begin{center}
\textbf{Questionnaire (Case Study 1)}
\par\end{center}
```

Comment: `\appendix` switches numbering to `Alpha`. Now you can add what you want to have in your appendix. Use `chapter` if you have `book` or `report`, sections otherwise.

Comment: I mean how to add appendix in lyx...

Comment: tab `Document` -> `Start appendix here`

Comment: Thanks, if i need to add any file (questionnaire), Do i need to add as an external material here?

Comment: I don't know, i don't use LyX.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is your question about `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and `\includepdf{questionnaire.pdf}`?

Comment: nops, now i am writing by hand in appendix box rather than insrting external file... Issue is when i compile my document, Appendix heading doesnt exist, above the page "Reference" is written (as i have added appendix after references). May be appendix is not included properly or what?

Comment: You might need to use a `\section{title of first appendix}`, or `\markboth{Appendix}{Appendix}` (if it is missing in the header) or `\appendixpage` (if you are using the appendix package).

Answer (score 1):

In your document, after the chapters, 
insert the appendix

```
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \mainmatter
    \input{chapter1}
    \input{chapter2}
  ...


    \appendix
    \cleardoublepage  
    \input{appendix1}
    \input{appendix2}
     ...
 \end{document}
```

where the appendix1 is defined in a appendix1.tex file:

```
%\appendix
\label{ref:appendix1}
\chapter{appendix1}

text
```

Comment: Labels always come *after* what they are supposed to label.

Comment: although `\chapter{appendix1\label{ref:appendix1}}` is also OK.